# Spinner in fragments pop up delayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner

I created some fragments in an `Activity` class as tabs where you can switch through and inside these I have various `Spinner`. The data I'm getting from a SQL-database with `JSONParser` and the `Spinner` gets created in the `fragment` classes as follow:

```js
spinnerMaterial = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Spinner_material);

        List<String> lables_material = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < materialList.size(); i++) {
            lables_material.add(materialList.get(i).getMaterial());
        }

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter_material = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables_material);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerAdapter_material
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinnerMaterial.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter_material);

        // spinner item select listener
        spinnerMaterial.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Actually everything is working. I'm getting all the data and the `Spinner` are poping up. BUT not in a direct way. So I need to switch between the tabs (`fragments`) and then go back that the `Spinner` is showing the data. Strange fact is that when I try to debug and go over some `breakpoints` the `Spinner` pops up immediately (without switching tabs).

Do you have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Please add the problematic sections of your code, so someone can help you. It's hard to tell what the problem is without the code.

Comment: We can not think of a idea without any code .